# $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$ both endowed with the discrete topology are homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

I've started reading 'Introduction to Topology' by Vassiliev and I stumbled upon this problem in the first chapter - prove that $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$ both endowed with the discrete topology are homeomorphic, but I can't think of a bijective map from the open sets of $[0,1]$ with the discrete topology (all points are open) to $(0,1)$ - where would the end points from the closed interval get mapped to in the open interval? Does anyone have a suggestion of how to start? Thank you.

Comment: Take a countable subset  of $[0, 1]$, including the endpoints, and map it to a countable subset of $(0,1)$. The identity function on what's left.

Comment: Note that in the discrete topology, *every* set is an open set. So as long as you have a set bijection between the two sets, then it will automatically be a homeomorphism.

Comment: to add to @GregMartin, in the discrete topology every function from the space to itself is continuous

Comment: More precisely, every function whose *domain* has the discrete topology is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two sets have the same cardinality.  Thus there is a bijection between them.  Any such bijection is a homeomorphism, since both it and its inverse map from spaces with the discrete topology.